# why isn't this code working? Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

JS :

```
  function loadprice(){
        $.getJSON('http://domain.com/pulsa/data.php',
            function(json){
            $("#pricebtcbuy").append(json.price.btcbuy);
            $("#pricebtcactu").append(json.price.btcactu);
            $("#pricebtcsell").append(json.price.btcsell);
            $("#pricedlrbuy").append(jsonprice.usdbuy);
            $("#ppsaldo").append(json.price.paypal);
            $("#pricedlrsell").append(json.price.usdsell);
});
setTimeout("loadprice()",5000
);
```

JSON FILE `{ "price": [ { "btcbuy": "Rp. 2.927.990,-", "btcactu": "", "btcsell": "Rp. 2.784.000,-", "usdbuy": "Rp. 12.853,-", "paypal": "1.00", "usdsell": "Rp. 12.223,-" } ] }`

Anyone know what is wrong here? Javascript ?? Thank you :D
the result is not show X_X

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Please check the url, you have specified

Comment: Welcome to SO. You way something is wrong here. You should tell us the error you get.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to show how to ask a good question. Your post is not very clear, please explain exactly what the issue is, what you have tried already, provide sample JSON response that you get etc

Comment: what makes you think anything is wrong?? I mean, you are using eval() but I'm guessing you don't mean that

Comment: you can parse json before use.
JSON.parse(json)

Comment: @mitul `$.getJSON` assumes that the response will be JSON and parses it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is value is properly indenting and formatting your code. You've missed the closing curly brace on `loadprice`.

```
function loadprice () {
  $.getJSON('http://domain.com/pulsa/data.php', function (json) {
    $("#pricebtcbuy").append(json.price.btcbuy);
    $("#pricebtcactu").append(json.price.btcactu);
    $("#pricebtcsell").append(json.price.btcsell);
    $("#pricedlrbuy").append(jsonprice.usdbuy);
    $("#ppsaldo").append(json.price.paypal);
    $("#pricedlrsell").append(json.price.usdsell);
  });
}
```

Also, are you trying to run this every 5 seconds? Or are you trying to run this after 5 seconds from when it's originally called?

If you want to call it after 5 seconds, you'll need to call `setTimeout` outside the function definition. You also don't need the parenthesis after the function name in this case.

```
setTimeout(loadprice, 5000);
```

This would also work, and hopefully it differentiates calling a function and passing an object.

```
setTimeout(function () { loadprice(); }, 5000);
```

If you want to run this once every 5 seconds you'd use `setInterval`. But if that's your desire there are better ways to do that.

```
setInterval(loadprice, 5000);
```

Still a better way yet is to utilize the [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) `$.getJSON` returns. This way it won't run every 5 seconds, but each time the request is completed the Ajax call will happen in another 5 seconds. This will avoid potential problems if the response takes more than 5 seconds to get.

```
function loadPrice () {
  var jqxhr;

  jqxhr = $.getJSON('http://domain.com/pulsa/data.php', function (json) {
    $("#pricebtcbuy").append(json.price.btcbuy);
    $("#pricebtcactu").append(json.price.btcactu);
    $("#pricebtcsell").append(json.price.btcsell);
    $("#pricedlrbuy").append(jsonprice.usdbuy);
    $("#ppsaldo").append(json.price.paypal);
    $("#pricedlrsell").append(json.price.usdsell);
  });

  jqxhr.done(function () {
    setTimeout(loadPrice, 5000);
  });
}
```

Comment: refresh every 5 seconds sir :D

Comment: Then read about `setInterval` and go with that for now.

Comment: But the best choice is to use a Promise. I just updated the answer with a basic example.